# Akka rejection handler to return JSON response

Tags: java, akka

I'm trying out things with Akka HTTP and I found this from the official [doc](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/rejections.html) and the snippet code goes like this

```
final RejectionHandler rejectionHandler = RejectionHandler.defaultHandler()
    .mapRejectionResponse(response -> {
    if (response.entity() instanceof HttpEntity.Strict) {
        // since all Akka default rejection responses are Strict this will handle all rejections
        String message = ((HttpEntity.Strict) response.entity()).getData().utf8String()
            .replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");
        // we create a new copy the response in order to keep all headers and status code,
        // replacing the original entity with a custom message as hand rolled JSON you could the
        // entity using your favourite marshalling library (e.g. spray json or anything else)
        return response.withEntity(ContentTypes.APPLICATION_JSON,
            "{\"rejection\": \"" + message + "\"}");
    } else {
        // pass through all other types of responses
        return response;
    }
});
```

Now I'm stuck where I need to convert the JSON type something 'cleaner' rather than string concatenation.

```
return response.withEntity(ContentTypes.APPLICATION_JSON,
    "{\"rejection\": \"" + message + "\"}");
```

I know I can use ObjectMapper() but I'm looking into a default way of gettings things done. The magic sauce method which would take Marshaller, class and the object to get the things done. 
Any ideas?

So far I've tried something like this

```
String message = ((HttpEntity.Strict) response.entity()).getData().utf8String();
HttpEntity.Strict jsonMessage = HttpEntities.create(ContentTypes.APPLICATION_JSON, message);

HttpResponse httpResponse = HttpResponse.create()
                           .withStatus(response.status().intValue())
                           .withEntity(jsonMessage);
return httpResponse;
```

But still, I get the text/plain response though content headers has been set to Content-Type →application/json.

Comment: Object mappers are unfortunately pretty much the standard for json / java. You could generate a temporary object to map. What do you think of that approach??

Comment: I was also trying to figure out a way to use the default `Jackson.marshaller()` to convert my error pojo into JSON, but wasn't able to figure out a way to do it. I ended up creating my own Jackson `ObjectMapper` and using it to marshall the object into a JSON string (i.e. the same thing that the default marshaller is doing under the hood).